# Does cv::Mat_ maintain its ROI?

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

Say I have a 100x100 `cv::Mat1b` called `image`. Then I do:

```
cv::Mat1b subImage = image(cv::Rect(0,0,49,49));
```

To get the upper left corner of `image` into `subImage`. Then say I pass `subImage` to a function, say `cv::findContours`. Will the resulting contours be relative to `image` or `subImage`? That is, does `findContours()` know that `subImage` is actually a sub-image? Or do all OpenCV functions just treat a `subImage` extracted like this as a "full image" and then it's the callers responsibility to add the corner of the extracted region to each of the coordinates of the contour pixels (in this example case) to get the contour as interpreted in the original `image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub-image is treated as a complete image, functions called on the sub-image  don't know it isn't a complete image.

The findcontour function however does take an optional parameter of the coordinates of the ROI so that contour coordinates are returned relative to the full image Alternatively you can simply add an offset to each contour point

Comment: Ah, I see that argument now, interesting. It's good to confirm that by default though nothing will assume that an image could be a subimage.

Comment: @DavidDoria, the functions do not handle sub-images differently (although the data is present to determine that they are a subimage) findcontour is a special case because you so often want to do this with contours

Answer (score 1):

If you declare subImage as:

```
Mat1b subImage = image(cv::Rect(0,0,49,49));
```

then `subImage` will be taken as a complete Mat object by any OpenCV function.
However, any change made in `subImage` will be reflected in the corresponding portion of `image` as well.

If you want to exclude the changes made in `subImage` from `image`, you should use:

```
Mat1b subImage = image(cv::Rect(0,0,49,49)).clone();
```

Now you have a `subImage` that is not pointing to `image`